# Looking for error in C++ Quicksort / Insertion sort combo

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

Im trying to build a the quicksort / insertion sort combo, as some say its fairly fast, as it tackles the larger subarrays with quicksort and the smaller arrays with insertion sort, but something is definitely not correct.  I've been testing the sorting with some files I generated.  I'm currently using a file of 1,000,000 numbers, with the range limit on each number being from 1 to 1,000,000.  Prior to adding the insertion sort, I was able to sort the 1 million numbers in about 0.2 seconds, after adding insertion sort as a conditional if statement, I'm lucky to sort 100,000 numbers in less than 4 seconds, so I know there's an error in the code, but I can't find it.  My code is just an amalgam of different online references for these types of sorting methods, I don't claim the code as my own and can provide links to the original if necessary.  However, the references I used weren't written in C++ and were class-oriented, so I had to make changes, which is why I think there's an error.

```
void modifiedQuickSort(arrPtr &arrayPointer, int first, int last)
{
    int firstTemp = first, lastTemp = last;
    int temp;
    int pivot = arrayPointer[(first + last) / 2];


    if((last - first) < 10)
    {
        insertionSort(arrayPointer, last + 1);
    }

    else
    {
        // Partitioning Step
        while (firstTemp <= lastTemp)
        {
            while (arrayPointer[firstTemp] < pivot)
                firstTemp++;

            while (arrayPointer[lastTemp] > pivot)
                lastTemp--;

            if (firstTemp <= lastTemp)
            {
                temp = arrayPointer[firstTemp];
                arrayPointer[firstTemp] = arrayPointer[lastTemp];
                arrayPointer[lastTemp]  = temp;
                firstTemp++;
                lastTemp--;
            }
        }

        // Recursive step
        if (first < lastTemp)
            modifiedQuickSort(arrayPointer, first, lastTemp);

        if (firstTemp < last)
            modifiedQuickSort(arrayPointer, firstTemp, last);
    }
}

void insertionSort(arrPtr &arrayPointer, const int &arraySize)
{
    int i, key, j;

    for (i = 1; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        key = arrayPointer[i];

        j = i-1;

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
         greater than key, to one position ahead
         of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arrayPointer[j] > key)
        {
            arrayPointer[j+1] = arrayPointer[j];
            j = j-1;
        }
        arrayPointer[j+1] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I'm very familiar with the debugger and it is what I have been using.  The problem is, the algorithm works.  There's no issue with sorting (so far).  However, the debugger isn't able to tell me why the algorithm isn't as efficient as its supposed to be, or even remotely close to being as efficient as just the Quicksort alone.  I'll try to edit this to help make it run-able for others.

Comment: Your insertion sort could be considerably more efficient by using a binary search on the already- sorted segment to look for the insertion point. That linear search will eventually add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the execution of the insertion sort you see that it gets to sort far larger arrays than size 10. This would have been caught, had you followed the excellent advice given in [Lipperts writeup](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) linked by πάντα ῥεῖ.

> If you’ve still got a bug then first double check that your specifications contain all the preconditions and postconditions of every method.

and

> If you’ve still got a bug then learn how to write assertions that verify your preconditions and postconditions.

The function call

```
if((last - first) < 10)
{
    insertionSort(arrayPointer, last + 1);
}
```

Indicates that `insertionSort` operates on the entire array `[0, last]` not `[first, last]`.

Change this and the performance of your `modifiedQuicksort` will behave as expected.

Comment: This fixed it.  Thanks.